# when will there be ICE support in firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc, ice

Does anyone have any idea as to how much time it will take or in which version of firefox , will there be full support for ICE similar to chrome ?

Also i would love to know about opera, regarding its support for webRTC.

I had googled about it , but looks like there is nothing related to ICE and firefox . ( please correct me if i am wrong )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. I guess no one really knows, but considering that support is available in the latest Nightly builds, the regular version of Firefox might get support in the next 3-6 months.

I get the feeling that all the browser makers are aiming for full (and hopefully unified) WebRTC support by the end of 2013.